# How to get login using JSON file in Android

Tags: php, android, json

Here is my Json Code I want make user login using User_Id form Json File

```
<?php
require '../db_connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']))
{
    $myusername = $_GET['username'];
    $mypassword = $_GET['password']; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE (username = '$myusername' or email = '$myusername' or phone = '$myusername')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

    $response["VerifiedMember"] = array();
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $VerifiedMember = array();
        $id=$row['id'];
        $phone=$row['phone'];
        $reg_type=$row['register_type'];
        $stored_salt = $row['salt'];
        $stored_hash = $row['hashed_password'];
        $check_pass = $stored_salt . $mypassword;
        $check_hash = hash('sha512',$check_pass);

        if($check_hash == $stored_hash){

            $VerifiedMember['user_id'] = $id;
            $VerifiedMember['first_name']=$row['first_name'];
            $VerifiedMember['phone']=$row['phone'];
            array_push($response["VerifiedMember"], $VerifiedMember);

         if(!empty($phone)&& $reg_type==1){

             $sql="select * from user_otps where user_id='".$id."'";
             $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
             if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if($row['verified']==0)
                {
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "failure";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);

                }
                else
                {   
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
             }
         }
         else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 1;
                      $response["message"] = "success";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
         }
         //echo json_encode($response);
        }

        else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    else{
                    //no product found
                      $response["success"] = 0;
                      $response["message"] = "invalid";

                    // echo no users JSON
                    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
?>
```

Android Code is here but its showing me correct details of user  in lOG file bt i m unable to go next activity using Intent in andoriod  and there of log file is pasted below please help me

```
06-13 13:08:06.503 30430-30570/com.shreejienterprisenic.register D/TESS ::: {"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"23","first_name":"karan","phone":""}],"success":1,"message":"success"}


    public class NewLogin  extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText editTextUserName;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    String username;
    String password;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    }

    public void invokeLogin(View view) {
        new loginAccess().execute();
    }


    class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        String access;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewLogin.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();



        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            String url = "www.sample.com/home_webservice.php";
            JSONObject json = null;

            try {



                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
              Log.d("TESS :: ", json.toString());
                String status = json.getString("VerifiedMember");
         Log.d("Success Response :: ", status);


                if (status.equals("VerifiedMember")) {


                    Intent i = new Intent(NewLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                else if
                        (json.getString("VerifiedMember").trim().equalsIgnoreCase("failed")) {


                    Toast.makeText(NewLogin.this, "Please enter the correct details!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block flag=1;

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the JSON I'm getting back:

```
{"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"15","first_name":"jaxi","phon‌​e":null}],"success":‌​1,"message":"success‌​"}
```

What is the cause of the exception?

Comment: Please help to make user login using json file @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: First it's a php code second what is your question here I didn't understand. Can you explain properly

Comment: Please help to make user login using json file @suraj

Comment: We cant code an app for you.. that is not the purpose of this site..Please read [ask]

Comment: i want to make android login app where user can directly login using their register email or phone number and password  in app 
he already register from website so give me code android @sumit

Comment: @karanbrahmaxatriya you have to check some tutorial before asking this question and try some code if you stuck on that then we will help you please show some efforts..

Comment: http://uat.ziplife.in/mobileapp/login_webservice.php upadted this link also

Comment: Actually when i m click on login button progress bar is open and dismiss bt thn after nothings happen and in LOG file it shows me error like doInBackground..java null pointer @EJoshuaS

Comment: Can you edit the question to include that information as well as the logcat for the error?

Comment: Log file updated @EJoshuaS

Comment: Thanks, that improves the question a lot.

Comment: now please sir help me how to login using webservice i m new in this area so and sorry for that @EJoshuaS

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what JSON is being returned by the web service? Apparently it's failing when it tries to parse the JSON, which seems to be causing the null pointer exception.

Comment: actually sir i hv created html form to get userdata in json when i login from html form i get this data  as in JSON format
{"VerifiedMember":[{"user_id":"15","first_name":"jaxi","phone":null}],"success":1,"message":"success"}
@EJoshuaS

Comment: username = chawdajaxi@gmail.com  password = 123456

Comment: sir please help to solve this issue @EJoshuaS

Comment: Cause of exception dont know @EJoshuaS

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743332/jsonparser-makehttprequest-error-in-json-parsing

Comment: I'm actually admittedly slightly lost, too... it seems like the JSON is ok... it appears that, for some reason, the parsing fails, so `json.toString()` seems to cause a null pointer exception (if I'm reading correctly). I voted to reopen, I'm actually curious about the answer to this too.

Comment: whts the problem in my code is in android side or php side ? @EJoshuaS

Comment: anyone help me please

Comment: you are retrieving valus from `_GET` and sending with POST..it fails the `isset` check and returns nothing

Comment: Thanx to everyone I got it wts the error thnx to all i just change POST to GET in android file and its work perfect..thnx to all @suraj

Comment: here i click on login button and getting correct detaills in LOG file bt i hve put intent in If success new activity open bt it doesnt open how to open new activity @EJoshuaS